# Clang environment variable for extra flags

Tags: clang

For which environment variable clang is sensitive? I tried setting CFLAGS and EXTRA_CFLAGS but seeing verbose clang compiling output (`clang -v`) I'm not finding there my custom added flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nor `clang` nor `gcc` look at the `CFLAGS` env variable. It is buildsystem that looks on that in puts its value into `clang` invocation. In your case just call `clang $CFLAGS ...`